# DHCPv6 isn't updating DNS

Tags: linux, ubuntu, domain-name-system, dhcp

I asked this on the Debian Users mailing list, but thought I'd ask here as well. I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 on ISC DHCP 4.3.3 and BIND9 9.10.3.

I'm having trouble getting my DHCPv6 server to update DNS and I'm not sure what I'm missing. From what I can tell I have everything setup and have tried numerous changes to the config file without success. Here is my named.conf.local file. I've tried allowing updates with both the update-policy and allow-update commands as well as through a key and just by IP address, but as far as I can tell the DHCP server isn't even attempting to communicate with the DNS server:

```
root@blldns01:~# cat /etc/bind/named.conf.local
//
// Do any local configuration here
//

// Consider adding the 1918 zones here, if they are not used in your
// organization
include "/etc/bind/zones.rfc1918";
include "/etc/bind/Kddns-aaaa-rrs.+157+11111.private";
include "/etc/bind/Kddns-ptr-rrs.+157+11111.private";

key DHCP_UPDATER {
    algorithm HMAC-MD5.SIG-ALG.REG.INT;
    secret "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX==";
};

zone "appendata.net" in {
    type master;
    notify yes;
    file "/var/lib/bind/db.appendata.net";
    allow-update { 2620:5:e000:201e::4:1; };
#    allow-update { key DHCP_UPDATER; };
#    update-policy {
#        grant "ddns-aaaa-rrs" self * AAAA TXT DHCID;
#    };
};

zone "0.0.0.e.5.0.0.0.0.2.6.2.IP6.ARPA" in {
    type master;
    notify yes;
    file "/var/lib/bind/db.2620.5.e000";
    allow-update { 2620:5:e000:201e::4:1; };
#    allow-update { key DHCP_UPDATER; };
#    update-policy {
#        grant "ddns-ptr-rrs" self * PTR TXT DHCID;
#    };
};
```

In my dhcpd.conf file I have my zones specified and have tried including the key file, declaring the key directly in the file, and simply not using the keys and just using IP based authentication. None of it has worked so far. I've also tried using primary and primary6 with the actual IP address in my zone declarations, but this hasn't made any difference:

```
#################
# DDNS SETTINGS #
#################
# The ddns-updates-style parameter controls whether or not the server will
# attempt to do a DNS update when a lease is confirmed. We default to the
# behavior of the version 2 packages ('none', since DHCP v2 didn't
# have support for DDNS.)
ddns-updates           on;
ddns-update-style      interim;
allow                  client-updates;
ddns-domainname        "appendata.net.";
ddns-rev-domainname    "ip6.arpa.";
do-forward-updates     on;

# Include keys used to securely communicate with the DNS server.
include                "/etc/keys/Kddns-aaaa-rrs.+157+11111.private";
include                "/etc/keys/Kddns-ptr-rrs.+157+11111.private";

key DHCP_UPDATER {
    algorithm    HMAC-MD5.SIG-ALG.REG.INT;
    secret       "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX==";
};

# Configuring zones for ddns-updates.
zone appendata.net. {
    primary    ns1-int.appendata.net;
#    primary6   2620:5:e000::a1;
#    key        DHCP_UPDATER;            # AAAA DNS key for RR's.
}
zone 0.0.0.e.5.0.0.0.0.2.6.2.ip6.arpa. {
    primary    ns1-int.appendata.net;
#    primary6   2620:5:e000::a1;
#    key        DHCP_UPDATER;            # PTR DNS key for RR's.
}
```

I've tried putting various options and declarations in different scopes, but none of it has worked. The DHCP server gives out an IP address just fine, but it doesn't look like it is even trying to update the AAAA and PTR records.

```
Jul 25 10:22:56 blldhcp01 dhcpd[1489]: Solicit message from fe80::216:3eff:fe32:2d49 port 546, transaction ID 0x9D08B00
Jul 25 10:22:56 blldhcp01 dhcpd[1489]: Picking pool address 2620:5:e000:201e:0:1:b41e:f2fe
Jul 25 10:22:56 blldhcp01 dhcpd[1489]: Advertise NA: address 2620:5:e000:201e:0:1:b41e:f2fe to client with duid 00:01:00:01:21:0a:2b:43:00:16:3e:32:2d:49 iaid = 1043475785 valid for 2419200 seconds
Jul 25 10:22:56 blldhcp01 dhcpd[1489]: Sending Advertise to fe80::216:3eff:fe32:2d49 port 546
Jul 25 10:22:57 blldhcp01 dhcpd[1489]: Request message from fe80::216:3eff:fe32:2d49 port 546, transaction ID 0x6C757900
Jul 25 10:22:57 blldhcp01 dhcpd[1489]: Reply NA: address 2620:5:e000:201e:0:1:b41e:f2fe to client with duid 00:01:00:01:21:0a:2b:43:00:16:3e:32:2d:49 iaid = 1043475785 valid for 2419200 seconds
Jul 25 10:22:57 blldhcp01 dhcpd[1489]: Sending Reply to fe80::216:3eff:fe32:2d49 port 546
```

And there is nothing in DNS's logs, even when set to DEBUG. Can anybody see what I'm missing. If I sniff the wire I can see that there isn't any communication between my DHCP and DNS servers, so I don't think its a firewall setting as its not even getting that far.

**Edit:** Both forward and reverse lookup zones are working correctly for DNS.

```
root@bllldap01:~# ping6 ns1-int
PING ns1-int(blldns01.appendata.net) 56 data bytes
64 bytes from blldns01.appendata.net: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.101 ms
64 bytes from blldns01.appendata.net: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.095 ms

root@blldns01:~# host 2620:5:e000::a1
1.a.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.e.5.0.0.0.0.2.6.2.ip6.arpa domain name pointer blldns01.appendata.net.
```

That's pinging the nameserver which is statically set in bind's configuration files. If I try to ping a server which obtained an IP address from DHCP it can't resolve the name, because DHCP isn't updating BIND.

```
root@bllldap01:~# ping6 bllldap01
unknown host
```

Comment: You sure dhcpd is trying to update ns-int over ip6?  Why not just use the key?

Comment: Yeah, I think that is the problem, that dhcpd isn't updating ns1-int. However, I've tried using primary6 and an IPv6 address of the DNS server, but this doesn't seem to have any affect. I have tried using the key as well, that also made no difference.

Answer (score 0):

Your reverse zone declaration is incorrect, it needs to be in "nibble" format for BIND configuration files, BIND doesn't parse the ip6 shorthand notation (2620:5:e000::a1).

2620:5:e000::a1, for example, would translate to 1.a.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.e.5.0.0.0.0.2.6.2.ip6.arpa.

[The IPv6 Reverse DNS](http://rdns6.com/nibble) site can help you here.

Comment: What about my BIND config file is not in nibble format? I don't specify 2620:5:e000::a1 inside BIND, so I can only assume you are getting this example from the DHCP config.  I have the zone delcared as: `zone "0.0.0.e.5.0.0.0.0.2.6.2.IP6.ARPA" in {`. That is my /48 that is allocated from ARIN in nibble format. I put the remaining reverse address in the actual file. If you are referring to the dot at the end of ip6.arpa, I added that and it made no difference. I can resolve addresses to hostname without any issue. The problem is that DHCP isn't updating. Could you be a little more specific?